# Setting up git large file storage

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have updated some files in my development project, and successfully committed them. When I try to push them, I get the error that the files are too large, and that I must set up git-lfs, and my push fails. What is the best way to set this up? Should I copy my project, reverse the commit, set up git-lfs and re-commit? Or is there someway to avoid this, by simply designating certain files for git-lfs?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to push on github you can't. According to github  [here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/):

**Conditions for large files**
GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.

**Removing large files from a repository**
To remove a large file from your repository, you must completely remove it from your local repository and from GitHub.

**Distributing large binaries**
Some projects require distributing large files, such as binaries or installers, in addition to distributing source code.

.....

Comment: thanks. but my file is already committed, will removing it from local/git repositories allow the push to occur, but without the file?

Comment: ah i see if i click the link it has instructions here:

https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/

thanks!

Comment: so i have done what they suggested, but when i tried to recommit, i still get the same failure, that the file is too large. if i try to remove the cached file, now it says it doesn't exist. do you have any suggestion(s)?